# How to compare the value entered as input is between values in table column1 and column2?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table named seri. In this table I have 2 columns named **balance_current_min** and **balance_current_max**. In these columns I generate random values between 3.5 and 3.6. I want to compare the cell_voltage (which is entered as input from the user) between the columns **balance_current_min** and **balance_current_max**.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[seri](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[seri_no] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[test_tarihi] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[test_operator] [int] NOT NULL,
[cell_voltage] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[voltage_min] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[voltage_max] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[cell_balance_current] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[balance_current_min] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[balance_current_max] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Cell_1] [nvarchar](50) NULL)


CONSTRAINT [PK_seri_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Comparison code:

```
private void textEdit1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double s1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtcell1min.Text);             
    double s2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtcell1max.Text);             
    double s3 = Convert.ToDouble(textEdit1.Text);

    if (s3 >= s1 && s3 <= s2)
    {
        checkEdit1.Checked  = true;
    }
    else
    {
        checkEdit1.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you are comparing the values in c# (hence the tag). Can you show that code please?

Comment: hello @sr28 i write my code in textchanged event. but it not works. This is my code thank you for your reply.  `private void textEdit1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            double s1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtcell1min.Text);
            double s2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtcell1max.Text);
            double s3 = Convert.ToDouble(textEdit1.Text);
             if (s3 >= s1 && s3 <= s2)
            {
                checkEdit1.Checked  = true;
            }
            else
            {
                checkEdit1.Checked = false;
            }

        }
`

Comment: Have you debugged to verify the values in the text boxes are what you expect and that s1, s2 and s3 are converting as expected?